# Filter one data frame to have rows with a field that matches another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `id_df` of ids:

```
id 
1434903254
3940505900
5902309590
...
```

and another data frame `df` with ids and some other fields:

```
id          field1  field2
3905094505  390300  929300
9503205909  030932  023039
3950259005  032030  023090
...
```

I want to filter `df` to have only rows with the ids from the `id_df`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
subset(df1, id %in% df2$id)
```